# Inverse of Continuous Function on Closed Bounded Part of R. Why Bounded?

Tags: calculus, continuity, inverse

Consider the following proposition:

Let $A$ be a closed bounded part of $\Bbb R$. Assume $f: A\rightarrow \Bbb R$ is a continuous injective function. Then $f^{-1}: f(A) \rightarrow A$ is also continuous.

So part of the condition is that $A$ needs to be closed and bounded. I see how these conditions help in proving the proposition and how an open $A$ would void the proposition, but I don't see why $A$ *needs* to be bounded.

What kind of functions would slip through otherwise? Is there a function that demonstrates the need for this condition?

Comment: Context: I'm studying for an exam and encountered a related question in the exercises. I'm not sure if this counts as 'homework'.

Comment: The result is certainly still true on an open interval. How are you seeing that the proposition fails on an open interval? Working in $\Bbb R$, it's true for any interval. Your statement needs to be modified, however: $f^{-1}$ has domain $f(A)$, not $\Bbb R$. (P.S. Your title says interval; your first sentence says "closed bounded part of $\Bbb R$." What *do* you want??!)

Comment: A question in the exercises of the book: We want to study the condition that $A$ needs to be closed _and_ bounded. Give an example of a continuous injective function $f: A\rightarrow \Bbb R$ on a closed but not bounded part $A$ of $\Bbb R$ where $f^{-1}$ is not continuous.

Comment: My mistake. To clarify: I'm talking about a closed part of $\Bbb R$, not necessarily an interval. I've updated the title.

Comment: Take $A=[0,1]\cup [2,\infty)$. Let $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ and $f(x)=1+2/x$ on $[2,\infty)$.

Comment: @David +1 ... You should make this an answer. But correct the typo on $[2,\infty]$ when you do that. :)

Comment: Thank you, David! I don't know why I didn't see it. In hindsight it's blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example: Take $A=[0,1]\cup [2,\infty)$. Define $f: A\rightarrow [0,2]$ by  setting $f(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $f(x)=1+2/x$ for $x\in [2,\infty)$.